# How to keep functionality of Control Text Color in subview?

Tags: swift, cocoa, fonts, subview, textcolor

I have a NSTableview with labels inside and outside of a subview.
When a row is selected, the color of the text in the textlabel should turn white.

[image]

In this case, `Status` and `Rank` both have Control Text Color, but only `Status` turns white when selected because it is not in a subview.

[image]

Is it possible to keep this functionality of the Control Color in a textlabel even when it is in a subview?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually code that, either by adding an extension or declaring a subclass and override the `setBackgroundStyle`, since `NSTableView` won't recursively call the function down to its subviews.

```
extension NSTableView {
    func setBackgroundStyle(_ newValue: NSBackgroundStyle) {
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.setBackgroundStyle(newValue)
        }
    }
}

extension NSTextField {
    func setBackgroundStyle(_ newValue: NSBackgroundStyle) {
        switch newValue {
            case NSBackgroundStyleDark:
                self.textColor = NSColor.controlHighlightColor
            case NSBackgroundStyleLight:
                self.textColor = NSColor.controlColor
        }
    super.setBackgroundStyle(newValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a absolutely reasonable approach. I tried a little bit, but there are some problems: view in subviews are NSView and not NSTextfield. So it doesn't recognize the `setBackgreoundStyle()`. Also in the NSTextfield extension, the `override func setBackgroundStyle` "does not override any metod from it's superclass".

Comment: Sorry, you simply implement the setBackgroundStyle function, no need to override, checked NSTableCellView class reference:  
  
_Upon setting, the default implementation automatically forwards calls to all subviews that implement -setBackgroundStyle: or are an NSControl (which have NSCells that respond to -setBackgroundStyle:)._

Comment: Alternatively you can implement `@objc var backgroundStyle: NSView.BackgroundStyle`. `@objc` is needed because `NSTableRowView` performs a dynamic lookup for the method.